# Adding new OnTouchListeners when a gesture has already started

Tags: android

I have Android service that draws a small transparent ImageView in a corner of the screen. This ImageView has an OnTouchListener that then draws a new view (a word cloud) when MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is triggered. When ACTION_UP is triggered the word cloud view is removed.

My problem is this: the word cloud view has it's own OnTouchListeners, however these are never triggered. I think this is because the current touch is being listened to by the onTouchListener of the first View and because the word cloud view is removed after ACTION_UP is triggered on the first view, the OnTouchListeners of the word cloud view are never triggered.

Is there any way to get the new OnTouchListeners (which are created while the user's finger is still on the screen) to be triggered without making the user lift his/her/its finger off the screen first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [this great talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) on mastering Android's touch system by Dave Smith.

Comment: Could you use the other Motion events? (e.g. ACTION_POINTER_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_UP)

Comment: @TylerOlson Not sure if this is what you meant, but the OnTouchListeners attached to the word cloud view didn't receive any Motion Events.

Comment: I'm thinking that the OnTouchListener for the word cloud view _is_ getting called, however the touch event is that of ACTION_POINTER_DOWN (called for all extra fingers placed on the screen) rather than ACTION_DOWN since there is already a finger on the screen. Can you add the case of ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and see if that does anything? Or just post some code?

Comment: @TylerOlson I tried to add the ACTION_POINTER_DOWN case, but it wasn't triggered. I'll edit my post with the relevant source code.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Thanks for the video; it was very helpful. However, I don't understand where my Word Cloud View is in the hierarchy relative to the original ImageView. Both are drawn using windowManager.addView().

Comment: You could try to use `dispatchTouchEvent` in your activity to manually dispatch the events to your view.